# Returning Exception to the caller function

Tags: c#, async-await, asp.net-web-api2, task-parallel-library

I have a function that prints generated ZPL. If the return value of PrintAsync function is null, my caller function creates `Request.CreateResponse<string>(ZPL)` and returns the ZPL, else it returns the message `Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.SeeOther, printerMessage);`

```
public async Task<Exception> PrintAsync(string zString)
{
      try
      { 
          await print(zString);
      }
      catch (Exception pe)
      {
         // assign pe to prop 
      }
      return prop;
 }
```

This works and I can easily know when something goes wrong while establishing the connection to a printer. Is that an acceptable way to be notified about the errors?

Comment: This is really non-standard. Why don’t you just take the standard approach, of letting the exception be thrown, i.e. remove the try/catch in PrintAsync and catch it in your caller where its necessary?

Comment: @ckuri I have many callers to this function, I thought this may be an easier way to go instead of handling every call on the controllers.

Answer (score 0):

If you can handle notifying the users of the error using a different method, like CreateErrorResponse, (utilizing thread safe "storage", such as a concurrent bag, to handle multiple concurrent requests from the same user), with enough information to correct the problem. Then there should be no issues with handling the thrown error earlier.